# How to suppress a build command's console output in waf?

Tags: python, build, waf

When using `waf` (https://waf.io) build system, how can I suppress output of a command from being printed to console, during build? The command is an external OS command and is invoked like this:

```
bld(rule='cmd ${SRC} ${TGT}', source='input.txt', target='output.txt')
```

Besides adding shell redirection to command, is there any waf option to accomplish this? How to suppress both stdout and stderr streams of command?

Comment: `> nul 2>&1` or `> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

You can [redirect](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) `stdout` and `stderr` (descriptor `1` and `2`, respectively) to `/dev/null` on non-Windows and to `nul` on Windows like this:

```
// In your wscript
import os

devnull = ('nul' if 'nt' in os.name '/dev/null')

def build(bld):
  bld(rule='cmd ${SRC} ${TGT} 1>' + devnull + ' 2>&1', source='input.txt', target='output.txt')
```